# Floating Point Number is greater than another floating point by how many points

Tags: javascript

I have function that accepts a  random floating point number as a parameter . The if condition in the function checks whether the floating number is equal to or greater than, by a specific  number of points , say `0.002` another floating point number x that is constant.
Below is the function that i had created.

```js
function checkRandom({ value }) {
  const x = 0.98334
  const diff = value - x
  if (value == x || (value > x) diff) {
    console.log("Match Successful")
  } else {
    console.log("")
  }
}
checkRandom(0.97)
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And please fix the indentation

Comment: This is not correct JS `if (value == x || (value > x) diff) {`  what is the diff doing there all by itself? I had to add quotes and a missing end `}` for the script to even look reasonable

Comment: @mplungjan in addition, the function parameter is destructured `({ value })` however, the argument provided is a plain number that will not have  a `value` property even if converted to an object.

Comment: _"I have function that accepts a random floating point number as a parameter"_ -- the function expects as argument an object, not a number. The object should have the property `value`, otherwise the value of the variable `value` in the function body is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this?

Passing {value}

```js
function checkRandom({value}) {
  const x = 0.98334
  const diff = value - x;
  console.log(diff)
  if (value == x || Math.abs(diff) < .002) {
    console.log("Match Successful")
  } else {
    console.log("Difference is greater than .002")
  }
}
checkRandom({value:0.98332})
```

Just passing a number

```js
function checkRandom(num) {
  const x = 0.98334
  const diff = num - x;
  console.log(diff)
  if (num == x || Math.abs(diff) < .002) {
    console.log("Match Successful")
  } else {
    console.log("Difference is greater than .002")
  }
}
checkRandom(0.98332);
```

Comment: Yes. This is what i meant. Thank you